# Pass value from one JtextField to another?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, settext

//New to java swing and need help getting the text in the first Jtextfield to display in the //second second jtextfield???? Im young and just starting out in java and need some help. below is the code i have done already thanks

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class lab4 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    int numClicks = 0;
    String text = null;

    public lab4() {
        setSize(1200, 700);
        setVisible(true);
        JButton button = new JButton("Hello i am a button");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));

        panel.add(button);
        this.add(panel);

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        this.setJMenuBar(menubar);
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        menubar.add(file);
        JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open File");
        file.add(open);

        final JTextField myField = new JTextField(10);
        myField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String text = myField.getText();
//System.out.println("Hello");

            }
        });

        final JTextField myField2 = new JTextField(10);
        yField2.setText(myField.getText());
        panel.add(myField);

        panel.add(myField2);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new lab4();

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        numClicks++;
        System.out.println("The button has been clicked " + numClicks + " times");

    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note, your `main` and `actionPerformed` methods are declared outside of the main class body and you have an extra `}`, which means your code won't even compile...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are doing ok. If more then one work going to happen in sequence on one action event, then you need to put the sequence inside the corresponding `actionPerformed` function. So:

```
myField.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String text = myField.getText();
    myField2.setText(text);

}
});
```

JComponents listeners mean that they will listen and respond only when an action event occur. They will be notified by the instance of `ActionListener` registered to event source(`JCompnent`) with `addActionListener()` function as you have done.

*One more thing to note*: you can't access a field in any statement before even declaring it.  Compiler's need to know the information about the field before doing anything with it. So you must declare `myField2` before the accessing-code of it, such as, `myField1`'s `anonymous class` `ActionListener`  `actionPerformed` function.

**Tutorial Resources:**

1. [Writing Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/)
2. [Anonymous Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can share the model:

```
JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(...);
JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(...);
textField2.setDocument( textField1.getDocument() ):
```

Now whenever you type text in either text field the other will also be updated.

Comment: congratulation on `100k` ;)

Comment: Thanks, its only taken me 1151 days... and counting ;)